# Explicit (full) specialization of function with a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template function declared as -

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T &t);
```

I have specialized it once as -

```
template <>
void foo<int> (int &t) {
    // Implementation for int
}
```

Now, I want to specialize the implementation for type - `template <typename T> bar<T>`. 
How should I be writing the specialization? Can I use template inside templates?

Comment: You can't partially specialize function templates. But you don't need to specialize anything here; just overload the function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah, I just realize that this would be a partial specialization and not a full specialization. I assume this would work for a class though? I will just stick to using overloading for now.

Comment: Yup, you can partially specialize classes.